# Помогите подстроить css стили под jss(material ui)

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Всем привет. Я делаю приложение на react и для стилизации использую material ui, в которой, на сколько я помню, используется синтаксис JSS. Мне понадобилось изменить стили при автозаполнении формы(autofill). Я нашел стили, которые мне нужны, но не могу корректно подстроить их под синтаксис jss. Собственно, прошу вашей помощи.

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active  {
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resetAutofill = {
  WebkitBoxShadow: '0 0 0 30px white inset !important'
}

// ...

inputClassName: {
  '&:-webkit-autofill': {
    ...resetAutofill,
    '&:hover': resetAutofill, 
    '&:focus': resetAutofill, 
    '&:active': resetAutofill
  }
}
```